# Does shorter code make a performance difference in interpreted languages?

Tags: java, python, ruby, perl, interpreter

Since the source code is interpreted while running, I think it might make a difference in Performance. What I mean is: 
When you have a long (>9000 lines) code and then cut out as many spaces and linebreaks as possible, does it make the program run faster? 
If so, does this apply to languages using bytecode (i.e. Java) too?

Comment: When you say *"shorter code"*, do you actually just mean the same code with less whitespace, or is that just an example? Given how long it takes to skip an empty line vs. parsing a non-empty line, what do you think?

Comment: *... cut out as many spaces and linebreaks as possible, does it make the program run faster?*  No, but it might shave a few milliseconds off the compilation time.  If you have performance issues then look elsewhere, this really is the strategy of the desperate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Python sourcecode (.py) is "compiled" into a representation that does away with all whitespace (.pyc). Instead of doing this transformation over and over again you can just run the .pyc files. So no, whitespace doesn't matter.

If you want performance the best thing to do is optimize your algorithm.

- Don't start peephole optimizing too early; clear, well-designed code is your first aim.
- After that, since your code is comprehensible and designed (hopefully) for insight and change, find out where the bottlenecks are: Look at the *"big-O"* complexity of your algorithms (`O(n)`, `O(n^2)`, etc.) and try to improve that.
- After that you might use a profiler to find remaining bottlenecks. You can often improve them easily since your code is well structured.

In short: Leaving out whitespace is no good. Understandable code is the way to optimization.

Answer (score 2):

> Since the source code is interpreted while running

This is incorrect, (afaik) in the languages you have tagged, the source code itself is compiled into a bytecode form, which is then interpreted by a virtual machine. This bytecode does not reflect the whitespace that is present in the source code, so no, whitespace will not affect the overall speed of executing the compiled program.

However, whitespace in the source code could affect the speed of compilation of the program, since the lexer/parser has more characters to consume and receive from the filesystem. Unless the file in question contains an extreme amount of unnecessary whitespace though, this shouldn't impact the speed in any noticeable way.

If you don't mean to ask about the presence of whitespace affecting the speed of compiling and interpreting a compiled program, then it is harder to say. The speed of interpreting a program will largely depend on the complexity of instructions used and the branching patterns used (if-statements, loops et.c).

For example, the following program will finish sooner before the second, even though there are more lines of source code.

```
public class Fast {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        foo();
    }

    public static void foo(){
        System.out.println("foo");
    }

    public static void bar(){
    }

    public static void baz(){
    }

}
```

Second program:

```
public class Slow {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        foo();
        foo();
        foo();
    }

    public static void foo(){
        System.out.println("foo");
    }

}
```

Comment: Console output is one of the most time-consuming things to do with simple programs (helloWorld-style). So of cause it runs faster. Also unused methods and variables are optimized away. But what about languages like Ruby? Ruby is not compiled before running

Comment: @Blackorade I was talking about the relationship between source code length and execution time...

Answer (score 0):

Java is not an interpreted language. Many other languages tagged above are also compiled into an intermediate bytecode instead of interpreted directly. Therefore length of source code doesn't relate to performance. Moreover in the program there maybe loops, which obviously takes less line but executed multiple times. A single-line program which loops infinitely will run longer than a program with a billion lines

Comment: Java is an interpreted language...

Comment: No, *.java files will be compiled to class files by java compiler, then it will be run by JVM

Comment: Exactly, which means that it is interpreted. If a language is interpreted, it doesn't mean that the actual source code is interpreted, rather it means that a compiled version of the source code is interpreted (run) by a virtual machine, rather than the physical CPU.

Comment: No. The bytecode will be compiled and optimized by the JITer or AoT compiler, not simply run the bytecode one by one

Comment: Actually, the compiled native code will be interpreted by the physical CPU. You *cannot* run *anything* without interpreting it. A compiler *only* translates from one language to another language. *Only* an interpreter actually runs something. "Compiled code" is simply the same program in a different language.